# update set where with sql in php

Tags: php, sql, database, sql-update

```
if (!empty($prijs)) {

    $sql = "UPDATE producten 
    SET prijs='$prijs', 
    WHERE product_id='$product_id'";

    $query = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
    $result = $query->execute();
    If ($result){
        print "Product aangepast!";
            }
  }
}
```

Whenever I try to update the database nothing happens. I added the print statement to confirm that the database was updated but it doesnt appear. Is there anything wrong with my sql code or maybe the part where the sql code gets executed?

Comment: Maybe `$prijs` is empty or undefined, or you're not properly connected to the db?

Comment: did you try to `echo` your query?

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "UPDATE producten 
SET prijs='$prijs' 
WHERE product_id='$product_id'";
```

I removed the comma after `'$prijs'` see if that helps

Comment: no it doesnt work.. could there be something wrong with this part: $query = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
    $result = $query->execute();